# Does Microsoft Dynamics Nav 2009 r2 supports SQL Azure?

Tags: azure-sql-database, navision

We are using Microsoft Dynamics Nav 2009 r2, Connecting with SQL Azure (SQL as service) causing issues of compatibility.

Can some one confirm that from which version of Navision supports SQL Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure SQL is officially supported since Dynamics NAV 2016 only:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn951458(v=nav.90).aspx
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nav/2015/10/09/hdi-set-up-nav-with-azure-sql-database-3/

Here is an older blog post with some limitations of Azure SQL which influence NAV:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nav/2011/01/14/dynamics-nav-and-sql-azure/